# maven-datanucleus-plugin fails to enhance classes

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, datanucleus

I get the following at the end of `datanucleus:enhance` step:

```
DataNucleus Enhancer completed with success for 0 classes. Timings : input=103 ms, enhance=0 ms, total=103 ms. Consult the log for full details
DataNucleus Enhancer completed and no classes were enhanced. Consult the log for full details
```

I verified that target directory is listed in the CLASSPATH: `WEB-INF/classes`

The individual class files are present under `WEB-INF/classes/com/company/*/*.class`

Here is the plugin declaration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0-m1</version>
            <configuration>
                <api>JDO</api>
                <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.0-m1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Why is datanucleus enhance plugin not recognising the class files even when CLASSPATH is correct?

Comment: and your INPUT to the plugin (in pom.xml) is what?

Comment: Are you asking how the <plugin> is declared in pom.xml? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: I see a <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props> line there. But there is no datanucleus.properties file in the project. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Can you give me some pointers as to where I can find datanucleus.properties that works with app engine?

Comment: What do you mean "app-engine" ? You mean Google's own Datastore (BigTable), or google-cloud-sql (mySQL) ? You seem to have 3.2.0-m1 of the Maven plugin yet have v4.1.0-m1 of the api-jdo plugin!!! Totally inconsistent. Docs for such a plugin are found at http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jdo/enhancer.html#maven

Comment: If debugging a Maven plugin ... passing "--debug" to Maven will tell you WHAT is going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72503/discussion-between-s33k-and-neil-stockton).

Comment: Is there some place where I can find which versions of the plugins work well with each other? The java.lang.NoSuchMethodError I encountered now seems to be because of that

Comment: 3.2.x works with 3.2.x. You haven't answered the question of "which AppEngine", and that defines what version to use.